# Storing strings into list from Python regex over a file

Tags: python, regex, list

I am using Python's regex to extract paths from a file and then trying to append the paths into a single list. The paths are specified in different lines in the file (`options`) as follows:

```
EXE_INC = \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/me/bMesh/lnInclude \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/mTools/lnInclude \
    -I$(LIB_SRC)/dynamicM/lnInclude
```

The function that I have is:

```
def libinclude():
with open('options', 'r') as options:
    for lines in options:
        if 'LIB_SRC' in lines:
            result = []
            lib_src_path = re.search(r'\s*-I\$\(LIB_SRC\)(?P<lpath>\/.*)', lines.strip())
            lib_path = lib_src_path.group(1).split()
            result.append(lib_path[0])
            print result
return (result)
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
['/me/bMesh/lnInclude']
['/mTools/lnInclude']
['/dynamicM/lnInclude']
```

However, as you can see I get three different lists, each obtained for one of the lines in the file, `options`. Is there a way to get these three paths in one list so that the values are available outside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure, you're creating a new list every time you find a match. So only create one list and just continue to append to it each time you find a match

```
def libinclude():
with open('options', 'r') as options:
    result = []
    for lines in options:
        if 'LIB_SRC' in lines:
            lib_src_path = re.search(r'\s*-I\$\(LIB_SRC\)(?P<lpath>\/.*)', lines.strip())
            lib_path = lib_src_path.group(1).split()
            result.append(lib_path[0])
            print result
```

Comment: Thanks @Greg. Indeed trivial!